# Accessing sqlite database which is password protected with the help of sqlcipher in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sqlcipher, node-sqlite3

I have followed this [procedure](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/how-to-encrypt-a-plaintext-sqlite-database-to-use-sqlcipher-and-avoid-file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database-errors/868), and have generate a database which is password protected with [sqlcipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher). Then I am making a connection by following [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) syntax.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

const db = new sqlite3.Database('path/to/database/file', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the in-memory SQlite database.');
});
var query = 'select COUNT(*) as count from table_name where column_name IS NOT NULL;';

        db.serialize(function () {
            db.all(query, function (err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    console.log(rows);
                }
            });
        });
```

My expectations were to get the query to be executed but getting error:
 **Error: SQLITE_NOTADB: file is not a database**.
I tried but did not found any solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the password you used for the encryption.
Use

```
pragma key='mypassword';
```

as your first statement, just after opening the database.

The whole idea of encrypted database is that you shouldn't be able to just "get the query to be executed", isnt't it?

Comment: Actually I tried a lot but could not find the syntax of applying PRAGMA key with **sqlite3**. But the PRAGMA key can be used with **Sqlcipher** in command prompt. The root problem is when using it with  sqlite3 in command prompt it gives the error: **file is encrypted or is not a database**.

Comment: Indeed you cannot open sqlcipher-encrypted database with "plain" sqlite3.
sqlite3 does not understand "pragma key". This is an extension made by Zetetics.
So if you use sqlcipher you must use it in both directions - for encrypting as well as for querying.
Probably you need some library which allows to use sqlcipher in JS.
I have no experience with this particular combination, but quick googling retrieved this one which seems suitable:
https://github.com/journeyapps/node-sqlcipher